# Problem with Cognito: Logins don't match. Please include at least one valid login for this identity or identity pool

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito

I have the following problem with AWS Cognito:
Objective: To register a user, confirm registration with email code, authenticate upon user confirmation successful, and run a dynamodb query.

Observed issue: The registration is successful, the email code is received, and when it is entered immediately after receiving it on email, the subsequent user authentication is successful, the credentials refresh is successful, and the dynamodb query works normally. On the other hand, when I wait at least one minute since receiving the code on email, the registration confirmation is successful, the subsequent user authentication is successful, but the credentials refresh prior to running the dynamodb query fail with the following error:

**NotAuthorizedException: Logins don't match. Please include at least one valid login for this identity or identity pool.**

I've been banging my head against this for two days and haven't got the slightest idea of what I'm doing wrong... please help?

This is my code:

```
cognitoUser.confirmRegistration(confirmationCode, true, function(err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    alert(err.message || JSON.stringify(err));
                    confirmUserRegistration();
                } else {
                    console.log('Confirmation successful');
                    
    
                    var authenticationDetails = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.AuthenticationDetails(authenticationData);
                    
                
                    cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
                        onSuccess: function(session) {
                            console.log('authentication successful', session);
                    
                            var idToken = session.getIdToken().getJwtToken();
                            
                            AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
                                IdentityPoolId: "pool correctly configured",
                                Logins: {
                                    ['cognito-idp.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/user pool correctly configured']: idToken
                                }
                            });
                            
                              // Refresh credentials
                            AWS.config.credentials.refresh((error) => {
                                if (error) {
                                    console.error(error);
                                } else {
                                    // Credentials refreshed successfully
                                    console.log('Credentials refreshed');


                                    
                                     AWS.config.update({
                                        region: 'us-east-2' 
                                    });
                                    
                                    
                                    const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
                                    

                                    queryCLIENTSDB(dynamodb).then(highestID => {
                                        console.log("Highest ID from DynamoDB:", highestID);
                                        
                                        highestID++;
                                        console.log("New ID", highestID);
                                        addUserToDynamoDB(highestID, username);
                                        
                                    }).catch(err => {
                                        console.error("Error querying DynamoDB:", err);
                                    });
    
                                }
                            });
```